# I want to edit the Brand name which is coming in while loop using ajax the data is in input type="text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to edit the Brand name which is coming in while loop using ajax the data is in input type="text" but the problem I am facing with that I am sending the data via id attribute but the problem is that id is unique can I send the data without id, Please Help me someone my code is as below or suggest me if any other way to send data in spite of id attribute my code is as below.

My code is as below :

// PHP Code is

```
<input type="text" data-id1="<?php echo $brand['brand_id'] ?>" id="update_text<?php echo $brand['brand_id'] ?>" class="form-control edit_box_input edit_input<?php echo $brand['brand_id'] ?> first_name" value="<?php echo $brand['brand_title'] ?>">
<span class="label label-info update_btn" update_id = "<?php echo $brand['brand_id'] ?>" >
    Update
</span>
```

---- and Ajax Code is ---

```
<script>
$("body").delegate(".update_btn", "click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var update_id = $(this).attr('update_id');
    var updatable_text = $("#update_text").val();
    $('.loading').fadeIn();
    $.ajax({
     url:"delete-n-more-action.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{update:1, update_text:updatable_text, updateID:update_id},
     success:function(data){
     fetch_brands();
     $('.loading').fadeOut();
     }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="parent">
    <input type="text" data-id1="<?php echo $brand['brand_id']; ?>" id="update_text" class="form-control edit_box_input first_name" value="<?php echo $brand['brand_title']; ?>">
    <span class="label label-info update_btn" data-id="<?php echo $brand['brand_id']; ?>" >
        Update
    </span>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on("click",".update_btn",function(){
        var update_id = $(this).data('id');
        var updatable_text = $(this).closest('div.parent').find("#update_text");
        var updatable_text_val = updatable_text.val()
        $('.loading').fadeIn();
        $.ajax({
            url:"delete-n-more-action.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{update:1, update_text:updatable_text_val, updateID:update_id},
            success:function(data){
                fetch_brands();
                $('.loading').fadeOut();
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The reason why I put the input and span inside a div because for the jquery [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to work, its use is for each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.